# the standard even grading on $M_2(A)$ and $A\otimes \mathbb{K}$

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, graded-rings

I have a question about a passage in Blackadar's book about K-Theory.

Let $A$ be a (ungraded) $C^*$-algebra. There is a grading on $M_2(A)$ with $M_2(A)^{(0)}$ the diagonal matrices and $M_2(A)^{(1)}$ the matrices with zero diagonal. This is an even grading with grading operator $diag(1,-1)\in M(M_2(A))$, where  $M(M_2(A))$ denotes the multiplier algebra of $M_2(A)$. We call this the standard even grading. By identifying $A\otimes \mathbb{K}$ with $M_2(A)$, we obtain the standard even grading on $A\otimes \mathbb{K}$.

My questions are:

1. How to understand the operator $diag(1,-1)$, i.e. what  is meant here with 1? Is this the identity operator  $M_2(A)\to M_2(A)$? But I'm not sure if it fits.
2. How does the standard even grading on $A\otimes \mathbb{K}$ look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $$g=\text{diag}\,(1,-1)=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$ You can easily check that 
$$
M_2(A)^{(0)}=\{a:\ gag=a\},\ \ \ \ M_2(A)^{(1)}=\{a:\ gag=-a\}.
$$

The standard even grading on $A\otimes\mathbb K$ is obtained by doing the above on $M_2(A\otimes\mathbb K)$ (diagonal matrices and matrices with diagonal zero). How it looks like depends on how you write the isomorphism $A\otimes\mathbb K\simeq M_2(A\otimes\mathbb K)$.

If we write $\mathbb K$ in terms of the canonical matrix units $\{E_{kj}\}$ and realize the isomorphism by decomposing $H$ as $(\sum E_{2k,2k})H\oplus (\sum E_{2k+1,2k+1})H$, then 
$$
A\otimes\mathbb K^{(0)}=\{\sum_{k,j}a_{kj}\otimes E_{kj}:\ a_{kj}\in A,\ \ a_{kj}=0\ \text{ if }k+j\text{ is odd }\},
$$
$$
A\otimes\mathbb K^{(1)}=\{\sum_{k,j}a_{kj}\otimes E_{kj}:\ a_{kj}\in A,\ \ a_{kj}=0\ \text{ if }k+j\text{ is even }\},
$$

Comment: thanks! But if $A$ is non-unital, for example if $A=\mathbb{K}$ (the compact operators on a infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space), what is meant with $1$ in this case?

Comment: The unit. That's why Blackadar writes that it is in the multiplier algebra.